# Poly-time reduction from HAMPATH to HAMPATH-E

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

I need to prove that 
HAMPATH-e = { < G,s,t,e > | G is directed graph, s, t are vertices and e a edge }
there is hamiltonian path between s to t that cross the edge e
is an NP complete.
i've already prove it's in NP.
now i need to show poly-time reduction from HAMPATH to HAMPATH-e but i cant figure it out.
any suggest?

Comment: That's certainly not the definition of HAMPATH-e: what _is_ the definition? And what did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help.

Comment: I've fixed the definition. i stucked because i can't think of a way to do the reduction. this isn't homework- i have a test in two weeks from now and i try to solve questions from past exams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which version of HAMPATH you're using, so I'll assume that for you, HAMPATH consists of all triplets $\langle G,s,t \rangle$ such that $G$ is a graph which contains a Hamiltonian path from $s$ to $t$. In that case, you can reduce HAMPATH to HAMPATH-E as follows: add a new vertex $s'$ and an edge $(s',s)$, and ask for a Hamilton path from $s'$ to $t$ through the edge $(s',s)$.